# Send test mail using telnet via smtps (465) port

Tags: linux, smtp, telnet, smtps

Based on this guide I am trying to send a test email using telnet from linux

https://linuxconfig.org/send-an-email-using-telnet

but the connection immediately disconnects:

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 108.177.126.108...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
MAIL FROM: asdasd@asd.Connection closed by foreign host
```

How do I keep the connection open long enough to send my test mail?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## SMTP session to smtps(465) port using telnet

Connections to smtp (25) start as unencrypted.
Connections to smtps (465) start/negotiate encryption before any SMTP protocol level communication.
You should get "SMTP greeting message" from SMTP server before sending any SMTP commands.

Classic/standard `telnet` does not support encryption (ssl - Secure Socket Layer).
You may check  if your telnet program supports it.

---

### Linux: Debian and Ubuntu

Package [`telnet-ssl`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/telnet-ssl) provides telnet variant with ssl support. It supports command line like below:

```
telnet-ssl -z ssl smtp.gmail.com 465
```

One on a few alternatives is provided by gnutls-cli program from `gnutls-bin` Debian package.

```
gnutls-cli -p 465 smtp.gmail.com
```

Comment: Ok any recommendation to a command line tool that supports smtps (465)?

Comment: @u123 Which Operating System (Linux distribution) do you use?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Also, HELO/EHLO comes before MAIL FROM

Comment: @u123 I have added hint for Linux Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: You may also have to add `--crlf` as some SMTP servers follow the spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.8 to the letter and expect every new line to be an actual CR followed by LF. Which is not how Linux works.

Answer (score 1):

Since this Q&A came up again on the front page

The canonical tool (almost always already installed as well) is `OpenSSL`

The relevant sub command to test both explicit TLS / SSL as well as [opportunistic TLS](https://enwikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS) SSL with startssl / starttls is  [`openssl s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/s_client.html)

```
openssl s_client -connect servername:465
```

And for opportunistic TLS on for example port 25

```
openssl s_client -connect -starttls smtp servername:25
```

Comment: You may also have to add `-crlf` as some SMTP servers follow the spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.8 to the letter and expect every new line to be an actual CR followed by LF. Which is not how Linux works.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct. You can use either `gnutls-cli` or `openssl s_client` to do a STARTTLS on port 465.

I just want to point out that some servers may still refuse to talk to you if your line endings are not Windows-style CRLF as the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.8) dictates.

> Lines consist of zero or more data characters terminated by the
> sequence ASCII character "CR" (hex value 0D) followed immediately by
> ASCII character "LF" (hex value 0A).  This termination sequence is
> denoted as  in this document.  Conforming implementations MUST
> NOT recognize or generate any other character or character sequence as
> a line terminator.  Limits MAY be imposed on line lengths by servers
> (see [Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4)).

Luckily modern implementations of gnutls-cli supports the `--crlf` flag, and openssl s_client has a `-crlf` to handle this problem.